# OpenWeatherMap returns incorrect current weather

Tags: json, weather, weather-api, openweathermap

I'm trying to implement an iphone app and i'm integration OpenWeatherMap to retrieve the current weather.  However, I've noticed the data returned is incorrect (off by about 39 degree Fahrenheit).

Below is the JSON URL i'm using to retrieve current weather for Denver, Usa using Lan/Lon coordinates where xxxxxxxxxxxxx is my APPID key.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&lat=39.738539&lon=-104.981114
```

The temperature returned was 291.05988.  From documentation read, this temperature unit is Kelvin.  So to convert to Fahrenhiet, I take 291.05988 - 254.928 = 36.13188 degree Fahrenheit. However, the true current weather is 75 degree Fahrenheit.  This is off by about 39 degrees.

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks
Loc

Comment: You're equation is converting to Celcius, not Fahrenheit. Even if it were converting correctly, [291K = 64F](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=291.05988+kelvin+to+farenheit) so it's still off.

Comment: I believe 1K = 274.15C.

Comment: Other way around. 1C = 274.15K. That still isn't Fahrenheit.

Comment: You're right, i had it reversed. If what i'm seeing is real, then all apps out there using OpenWeatherMap may potentially showing bogus data.

Comment: The equation I used was wrong. See below.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I'm answering my own question...

I was naived to believed the comments written by OpenWeather and had my calculation from Kelvin to Fahrenheit all wrong. From [OpenWeather's link here](http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Weather_Data), it states:

> Temperature in Kelvin. Subtracted 273.15 from this figure to convert
>   to Celsius.

That statement is WRONG. To convert from Kelvin to Fahrenheit, use this equation:

```
° F = 9/5(° K - 273) + 32
```

Hope others won't get tripped by that statement like I did.

Comment: The statement is **right**. It is about converting Kelvin to **Celsius**, not Fahrenheit. Celsius is used in many european countries excepting Great Britain.

Comment: haha, just stopped by your comment @SergeBallesta, "Celsius is used in many european countries". You're probably from the USA because as far as I know, all other countries in the world now use the Celsius, even Great Britain :). Voila, just wanted to correct this statement.

Comment: Read more carefully the comment I'm replying to @Max. I added "even GB" because SergeBallesta mentioned "excepting GB". And I'm not even mentioning Europe at all, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Max, GB is generally not considered a European country (regardless of EU status).  There's even a term: "continental," that refers to countries on the European continent at the exclusion of GB.  If you want to be pedantic about it (which I always do), there is no European continent at all; there is a Eurasian continent, and an Indian continent that are jammed together fairly hard.  "Europe" is a made up construct, mostly from historic arrogance, ignorance, and superiority complexes.  Nowadays it's used to distinguish certain countries for convenience, but doesn't include GB and never has.

Answer (score 15):

For those cruising by later, you don't need to do any conversions for Fahrenheit, you can add another query param to your request for that:

Fahrenheit: **units=imperial**

... also the option for
Celsius: **units=metric**

Example being:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=XXXXXX&units=imperial
```

Found this [here](http://openweathermap.org/current#data).

Comment: You saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way if you use in post url: `&units=metric` or it will be necessary to create a variable city and key:

```
city = 'London'
key = 'some_key'
```

So it will look like this :

```
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}&units=metric'.format(city,key)
```